# After creating .exe file my flutter application (windows based) runs in background

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

I have made my flutter project (windows platform) using android studio, I build the application than use inno setup to create a setup file but when I run the application after installation it runs in background not in foreground. I am creating windows based flutter application for the first time. I might miss some important thing like permission or something else please guide me how can I fix this issue. Also when I build the application and I run it from the release folder I works fine.

If you want to see any part of the code or anything else I can provide you. I don't know what are the relevant things to share.

I am using following dependencies(might be relevant):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  motion_toast: ^2.7.8
  sqflite_common_ffi: ^2.3.0+2
  path_provider: ^2.1.1
  intl: ^0.18.1
  image_picker: ^1.0.4
  get: ^4.6.6
```